# OSM API how to get all suburbs by city?

Tags: api, rest, geocoding, webservice-client, openstreetmap

Can someone tell me how to get a list of suburbs by city (name,id,whatever) in OpenStreetMap API? I can't find any detailed documentation and the API is pretty abstract.

I'm looking at extended API, Xapi. I found how I can get nods and filter only suburbs, but I don't know how to set the city value.

```
http://www.informationfreeway.org/api/0.6/node[place=suburb]
```

Any other way or API is welcomed. Looked at geonames and google maps, but haven't found what I'm looking for. I need a list of all suburbs in *Zagreb/Croatia* and a way to check if a specific street is in that suburb. OSM has a pretty good and accurate data as I can see, but I'm having troubles with this API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the bounding box and then filtering the results to ensure that they are actually within Zagreb?

Here's a URL using a bounding box created on openstreetmap.org
http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/node[place=suburb][bbox=15.807,45.761,16.18,45.875]

This gives you names, but since I'm still new to OSM, I'm not quite sure how you establish their admin level and whether they actually lie within Zagreb or just within that bounding box. There may be further requests that could establish this info.

Comment: This I probably the right answer, although not exactly what I was looking for. I gave up on OSM temporarily. Thank you anyway

Comment: Perfect, it can search for postal codes, city names and even street address fragments :D

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes I would use [OSM Server Side Script](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Server_Side_Script)

[here is the documentation](http://78.46.81.38/)

Comment: Why can't someone make a understandable api for OCM!?!?!? OSM Server Side Script look ok, but the API is a nightmare as well.

Comment: The api wasn't maked for downloading data by hand but by Programs.
The API is for uploading and editing the data, not for geocoding.